# Displaying alert in the main template

Tags: django, django-views

In my application I have set up a main template, all other templates are an extension for it. The main template only includes static data.

**Objective:** I want an alert - small crimson bar at the top - to be displayed at **all** pages served by the app.

**Current solution** is to just write it in raw HTML in the main template.

My views are all set up as follows:

`urls.py`:

```
url(r'^exam/(?P<exam_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.exam, name='exam'),
url(r'^person/(?P<person_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.person, name='person'),
...
```

`views.py`:

```
def exam(request, exam_id):
    exam = get_object_or_404(Exam, pk=exam_id)
    return render(request, 'exam.html', {'exam': exam})
def person(request, person_id):
    ...
```

I.e. all are quite primitive and main_template itself is not mentioned anywhere except for in the templates themselves.

To make alert dynamic and configurable from django-admin, I am planning to:

- Create a model for it:

  - Makes sense, since the alert might have some properties beyond base 'message content'
- Somehow design and write a view that would populate the main template with dynamic content.

**Question**:
How do I refactor the views to reach the objective - make the main template dynamic - while breaking current views as little as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions would be to create a model for storing your alert. The create an inclusion tag (check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)). In this way you can add this tag to whichever template you want (possibly base.html create an alert block and use this tag inside that block). This will ensure that with minimal refactor of your code you'll get the feature you want following the best practice. Hope this helps .. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to have a small alert on your exams page.(exams.html)

Create a simple model,

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "date_added"
```

In your current views.py,

```
def exam(request, exam_id):
    exam = get_object_or_404(Exam, pk=exam_id)
    alert = Alert.objects.latest() # Get latest alert message

    # Pass alert object along with other variables.
    return render(request, 'exam.html', {'exam': exam, 'alert': alert})
```

In your exams.html template

```
<div class='alert'>
    <p>{{ alert.message }}</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying, however, the alert should be not only in exam.html, rather in person.html, module.html, etc - **all** pages should have it.

Comment: Make a custom template tag as Tarun suggested.